# casting from geomoetrycollection with multiple nested geometries r sf

Tags: r, r-sf

This question is related to [How to simplify a MULTISURFACE, CURVEPOLYGON, or COMPOUNDCURVE geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68810009/how-to-simplify-a-multisurface-curvepolygon-or-compoundcurve-geometry). I am posting a new question that extends beyond the initial problem posed there and includes a reproducible example. You can cast a multisurface geometry to a geometry collection, then use lapply to go through the geometry collection and cast to polygons. However, this does not seem to be true when there are multiple nested geometries within a geometry collection. For example, in the code below I show how to convert a geometrycollection with a CURVEPOLYGON to a multipolygon, however in the second example the feature has multiple geometries and therefore throws an error.

The format of the first example is:

```
CURVEPOLYGON (
  LINESTRING ())
```

The format of the second example is:

```
CURVEPOLYGON(
       COMPOUNDCURVE(
              LINESTRING(...),
              CIRCULARSTRING(...),
              LINESTRING(...),
              CIRCULARSTRING(...),
              CIRCULARSTRING(...),
              LINESTRING(...)))
```

How can both of these be converted to multipolygons in an efficient way? Does lapply need to be used differently depending on the nesting structure? I have tried many different approaches but with no success.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Download example data
# This repo available: https://github.com/ARMurray/example_data
# gpkg: https://github.com/ARMurray/example_data/blob/master/data/gc_cast.gpkg

# load data
sf <- st_read("./data/gc_cast.gpkg")
#> Error: Cannot open "./data/gc_cast.gpkg"; The file doesn't seem to exist.

# A singular CURVEPOLYGON
cp <- sf%>%
  filter(COMID == "167120949")
#> Error in filter(., COMID == "167120949"): object 'sf' not found

# extract nested geometries
geoms <- lapply(cp$geom, `[`)
#> Error in lapply(cp$geom, `[`): object 'cp' not found

# cast to different geom
mp <- lapply(geoms, function(x) sf::st_multipolygon( x = x ) )
#> Error in lapply(geoms, function(x) sf::st_multipolygon(x = x)): object 'geoms' not found

# Create sf object
sf_mp <- sf::st_sfc(mp)%>%
  st_sf()
#> Error in sf::st_sfc(mp): object 'mp' not found

# Check and Plot
sf_mp
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'sf_mp' not found
plot(sf_mp)
#> Error in plot(sf_mp): object 'sf_mp' not found


# Multiple CURVEPOLYGONS
mcp <- sf%>%
  filter(COMID == "21411435")
#> Error in filter(., COMID == "21411435"): object 'sf' not found

m.geoms <- lapply(mcp$geom, `[`)
#> Error in lapply(mcp$geom, `[`): object 'mcp' not found

# This throws error: "Error in vapply(y, ncol, 0L) : values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0"
m.mp <- lapply(m.geoms, function(x) sf::st_multipolygon( x = x ) )
#> Error in lapply(m.geoms, function(x) sf::st_multipolygon(x = x)): object 'm.geoms' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_United States.utf8
#>  ctype    English_United States.utf8
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2022-11-17
#>  pandoc   2.19.2 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  class         7.3-20  2022-01-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  classInt      0.4-8   2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  cli           3.4.1   2022-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  DBI           1.1.3   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  digest        0.6.30  2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.10  2022-09-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  e1071         1.7-12  2022-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  evaluate      0.18    2022-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  generics      0.1.3   2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.3   2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  KernSmooth    2.23-20 2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  knitr         1.40    2022-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  pillar        1.8.1   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  proxy         0.4-27  2022-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.9   2022-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  reprex      * 2.0.2   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  rlang         1.0.6   2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.18    2022-11-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  rstudioapi    0.14    2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  sf          * 1.0-9   2022-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  stringi       1.7.8   2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  stringr       1.4.1   2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  tibble        3.1.8   2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.2.0   2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  units         0.8-0   2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  vctrs         0.5.0   2022-10-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  xfun          0.34    2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#>  yaml          2.3.6   2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/Users/AMURRA02/RPackages
#>  [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data using `dput()`, thank you.

Comment: Also if you post your question here https://gis.stackexchange.com, you might get an answer quicker.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a way to do this strictly in R, but the [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) utility was able to convert the curves to polygons, and remove the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` type.

---

##### Edit:

Turns out you *can* do it all in R:

`gdalUtilities::ogr2ogr('input.filename', 'output.filename', explodecollections = T, nlt = 'CONVERT_TO_LINEAR')`

Output looks the same as illustrated below.

---

Below I used R's `system` command, but it can be done separately on the command line outside of R beforehand. The general syntax is:
 `ogr2ogr output.filename input.filename -explodecollection -nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR`

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# read original file as sf object
sf1 <- st_read('/home/x/Downloads/gc_cast.gpkg')

# use ogr2ogr to 'explode' GEOMETRYCOLLECTION and 
#  convert curve geometries to polygons
system('ogr2ogr  /home/x/Downloads/output.gpkg /home/x/Downloads/gc_cast.gpkg -explodecollections -nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR')

# read newly created file as sf object
sf2 <- st_read('/home/x/Downloads/output.gpkg')

# take a look at new data & get geometry types
sf2
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -114.4936 ymin: 32.81916 xmax: -89.30414 ymax: 43.09026
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#>       COMID Area_Current_Km Near_Int yearCompleted Area_Old_Km ORIG_FID
#> 1 167120949     22.37534815       31          1938 22.37534815     7622
#> 2  21411435      0.02400404        6          1937  0.03111449      851
#>                fldd_zn           MAX_fldd_z STATE_ABBR STATE_FIPS Shape_Length
#> 1       cool temperate       cool temperate         WI         55   0.44919727
#> 2 tropical dry/montane tropical dry/montane         AZ         04   0.01450313
#>     Shape_Area                           geom
#> 1 2.471884e-03 POLYGON ((-89.33469 43.0900...
#> 2 2.311433e-06 POLYGON ((-114.4936 32.8237...

st_geometry_type(sf2)
#> [1] POLYGON POLYGON
#> 18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE
```

Above the new object `sf2` has `geom` column of POLYGON, rather than GEOMETRYCOLLECTION and CURVE type geometries.

Plotting the two objects to make sure everything looks about the same.
The two areas (row1 & row2) are far apart, so I've plotted them separately below.

```
# plots
p1a <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf1[1,]) +
  ggtitle('old w/curve geo')
p2a <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = sf2[1,]) +
  ggtitle('new w/polygon geo')

p12b <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = sf1[2,], alpha = .2, color = 'red', lwd = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = sf2[2,], alpha = .2, fill = 'blue') +
  ggtitle('old(red) & new(blue) overplotted')

p1a + p2a
```

[image]

```r
p12b
```

[image]

```r
# Truncated sessioninfo
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2022-11-19
#>  pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/quarto/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source

#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.5   2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  patchwork   * 1.1.1   2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  sf          * 1.0-10  2022-11-17 [1] Github (r-spatial/sf@12f931b)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.1   2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  units         0.8-0   2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: great answer! don't know why the OP didn't accept it.